# VueJs 3 - Custom Input Component

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I'm trying to build a custom HTML `<input>` component for VueJS3. I've been following this tutorial:

https://dev.to/viniciuskneves/vue-custom-input-bk8

So far I managed to get the `CustomInput.vue` component to work and emit the modified value back to the parent App.Vue.

```
<template>
<label>
{{ label }}
<input type="text" :name="name" :value="value" @input="onInput" @change="onChange" />
  </label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomInput',
      props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      return this.label.toLowerCase();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
    },
    onChange(event) {
      this.$emit('change', event.target.value);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

What I don't understand is - how will the emitted events be detected by the parent App.vue component? I can't see it happens, and I can't find it in the tutorial.

My `App.Vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
<custom-input :label="'Name'" :value="name"></custom-input>
<div>{{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import customInput from "./components/CustomInput.vue";

export default {
  components: { customInput },
  name: "App",
  data: function () {
return {
  name: "",
};
  },
  mounted() {
    this.name = "Thomas";
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tutorial is for Vue 2 - for Vue 3 there is another tutorial (https://www.webmound.com/use-v-model-custom-components-vue-3/)

Emitting `input` event works in Vue 2 only - for Vue 3 you will have to emit `update:modelValue` and also use `modelValue` as a prop instead of just `value`.

Comment: Thanks Ivo Gelov for the link to the Vue3JS Tutorial - I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right in your template.

```
<custom-input :label="'Name'" :value="name" @change='name=$event' @input='name=$event'></custom-input>
```

You can also use a method or computed with setter as well.